# Orthographic projection setup

Tags: c++, opengl, orthographic

I installed all the elements needed (shaders,vao/vbo,binding,drawing), but my form still does not appear . If I omit the view and projection matrices, the form appears but if I add them all disappears, what I forgot to include in the following code:

## Edited code that works :

**main.cpp :**

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <vector>

#include "ShaderProgram.h"
#include "VHandler.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    /*************************************/
    ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits = 24;
    settings.stencilBits = 8;
    /*************************************/

    /*************************************/
    Window window(VideoMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT),
                  "GLWindow",
                  Style::Titlebar|Style::Close,
                  settings);    
    bool running = true;
    /*************************************/

    /*************************************/
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    /*************************************/

    /*************************************/
    ShaderProgram shader;
    shader.loadShaders("shaders/vShader.vert","shaders/fShader.frag");
    /*************************************/

    /*************************************/
    /**VAOs & VBOs**/
    vector<float> vertices{{0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f}};

    vector<float> colors{{1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}};

    VHandler handler;
    handler.loadData(vertices,colors);
    /*************************************/


    /*************************************/
    GLuint uniProjection = glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(),"projection");
    GLuint uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(),"view");
    GLuint uniTransform = glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(),"transform");

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1);
    projection = glm::ortho(0.0f,static_cast<float>(WIDTH),static_cast<float>(HEIGHT),0.0f,1.0f,-1.0f);
    /*************************************/

    while(running)
    {
        Event windowEvt;
        while(window.pollEvent(windowEvt))
        {
            if(windowEvt.type == Event::Closed){running = false; break;}
        }

        /*************************************/
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        /*************************************/

        /*************************************/
        shader.startProgram();
        handler.bindVao();
        /*************************************/

        /*************************************/     
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProjection,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glm::mat4 view;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

        glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1);
        transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTransform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));
        /*************************************/

        /*************************************/
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        handler.unbindVao();
        shader.endProgram();
        /*************************************/

        /*************************************/
        window.display();
        /*************************************/
    }

    /*************************************/
    handler.cleanMemory();
    shader.cleanShaders();
    window.close();
    /*************************************/

    return 0;
}
```

**vertexShader :**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
Color = color;
//gl_Position = projection * view * transform * vec4(position, 1.0); //Can't see anything
//gl_Position = projection * transform * vec4(position, 1.0); //Can't see anything
gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0); //Works correctly
}
```

If i understand the operation of orthographic projection, my form should appear at the top left with 10px width and height, but I do not know what i'm missing.

Comment: Reduce the code to the minimum.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I can see your projection (ortho) transformation matrix. I can not see your view transformation matrix. Your 'transform' matrix is not a view transformation.

Comment: this is Minimal, (not complete) beceause of the shader, vao and vbo code, but if you want i can add them all in a single code

Comment: @Ripi2 i didn't get it, look inside the loop i set the view matrix, it's not that ?

Comment: No it isn't. You need a matrix that changes 'z' sign. You can use glm::lookAt().

Comment: i tried this but it did not solve my problem : `view=glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0,0,1),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));`

Comment: Why do you use `glUniform***` for the projection matrix before using the shader (your shader.startProgram()) ?

Comment: exactly, This is where the problem lies, thank you very much @Ripi2  i'll edit my code for people who need it.

Comment: Normally you keep apart the question from the answer. If you found the solution post it in an answer instead of editing the question, so another user can get some help from the post. This time it has no great importance, but please don't do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is, as commented by @Ripi, to use :

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProjection,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

after activating the shader `shader.startProgram();` So that the matrix is taken into account inside the vertex shader.